# connect to my wamp server with the android emulator with local. web address

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've read a bunch of articles on SO and around the web that all tell me that the android emulator connects to my machine with the ip address `10.0.2.2` when using `localhost`. Unfortunately I'm not using `localhost`, I've edited my hosts file so that I connect to `local.blah.com` when I want to view my webpage.

I thought that if I write: `10.0.2.2        local.blah.com` in my host file it would allow my to see the webpage I am developing in the android emulator. (Please correct me if this was not a good assumption)

So My question is what else can I try to get my `local.` url to work on the android emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either set up a local DNS server, or else you can only use the IP address, which should work.

Comment: The IP address will not work because of http.conf which tells local.blah.com to get the files out of a directory on my computer. Have you ever installed a local DNS server, if so do you have any pointers

Comment: If you are using Windows, there is one included. Here are some instructions to set it up from the beginning: http://www.petri.co.il/install_and_configure_windows_2003_dns_server.htm or here is an open source alternative http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/

Comment: thanks for the help. I figured out a solution modifying my site code and using localhost.

Comment: @locrizak: Are you happy to share it?