# Access local server with android emulator

Tags: android, wamp, local

I have a local server running with wamp. I would like to open a web browser in the Android emulator to access a local website. I tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 (they yield "not found") and my ip address (yields: "you don't have permission").

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Try these similar sounding threads:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905315/error-connection-refused/4905367#4905367


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721281/im-unable-to-call-a-servlet-from-my-android-application/4721383#4721383


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844576/connect-to-my-wamp-server-with-the-android-emulator-with-local-web-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your ip address is correct. If it gives you "you don't have permission" then you should configure WAMP to accept remote connections (i.e. connections other than localhost)

Comment: Could you be more specific on where I can change this permission?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when you right click the wamp icon you have an option called "Put it online". (I don't have access to wamp on this pc so I'm not sure if it's there or in some hidden menu).

Comment: Maybe here you can find some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003644/how-can-i-put-my-wamp-online-for-someone-to-access

Comment: Ok the "Put it online" button is right at the bottom when you left-click the wamp icon, that's why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` .
`127.0.0.1` is the localhost address of Android os . When you establish a web server in your android emulator you should use `127.0.0.1` , but when you want to access to localhost in your computer you should use `10.0.2.2` .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like http://localhost.run/ or https://ngrok.com/ to temporarily put localhost on the internet and access the site from the android emulator.